# View.onClickListener - how to get view properties

Tags: java, android

I m new here and I've got a question for which I haven't found answer yet.
I am trying to get some variable value from a clicked object using onClickListener.

This view is an object (actually its a ConstraintLayout) created previously with a boolean value.

Code (that is not the current code I've got but you get the idea hopefully):

```
public class layoutView extends ConstraintLayout {
    boolean bool = false;
    public layoutView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    ...
}
```

I am adding this layoutView into my main layout and its working fine but I need to get this boolean value when i click the layout view.

```
layoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); //this works fine
                boolean check = v.bool //this wouldnt work
                if (v.bool == true)... //this woulnt work
  }
});
```

Is it possible at all. How to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try casting View v to `layoutView` ? But there are more things wrong with your code..

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Casting View v to my class (ConstraintLayout) solved the problem!
if ((layoutView)v).bool == true) ...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `layoutView.setTag()/getTag()` instead of keeping your own variable `bool`.

Note that you may need to use a `Boolean` object instead of primitive type, for example:

```
layoutView.setTag(new Boolean(true));

// inside on click listener
if (v.getTag() == true) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.